# google map not displaying on mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

hello guys I am using meteor-google-map. I can see them on the desktop but on mobile I can't see them. Can anybody tell me what is it that I am doing wrong ?? on the mobile the map container is all blank. Here is an image

[map not appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kb2a.jpg)

If I have to white list the domains then can somebody tell me that how would I white list the google map because from the documentation which is

> tel:, geo:, mailto:, sms:, market:* are allowed and launch externally (phone app, or an email client on Android)

I think google map is allowed

here is the google map code

index.html

```
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="exampleMap" options=exampleMapOptions}}
  </div>
```

index.js

```
    exampleMapOptions: function() {
    // Make sure the maps API has loaded
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      // Map initialization options
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(Meteor.user().profile.latitude, Meteor.user().profile.longitude),
        zoom: 13
      };
    }
  }

Template.body.onCreated(function() {
  // We can use the `ready` callback to interact with the map API once the map is ready.
  GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
    // Add a marker to the map once it's ready
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: map.options.center,
      map: map.instance
    });
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

I found out I was getting the error uncaught referenceerror: google is not defined

so I tried white listing but it is not working

```
> App.info({   id: 'com.example.matt.uber',   
>name: 'MedCircle',  
> description: 'Get über power in one button click',   
>author: 'Matt
> Development Group',   
>email: 'contact@example.com',   
>website: 'http://example.com' 
>}); 
> 
> App.setPreference('BackgroundColor', '0xff0000ff');
> App.setPreference('HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar', true);
> App.setPreference('Orientation', 'default');
> 
> 
> // App.accessRule('*.googleapis.com'); 
> //App.accessRule('*.gstatic.com'); 
>// App.accessRule('*.google.com'); //
>// App.accessRule('maps.googleapis.com'); 
>// App.accessRule('maps.gstatic.com'); 
>// App.accessRule('mt0.googleapis.com'); 
>// App.accessRule('mt1.googleapis.com'); 
>// App.accessRule('csi.gstatic.com');
> 
> 
> // <access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" /> 
> //<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" /> 
> // <accessorigin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" /> 
> // <accessorigin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />
> 
> App.accessRule('*');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out I had to allow these to

```
App.accessRule('http://*');
App.accessRule('https://*');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "kind of"? I'm working on an app that will use google maps with dburles' package (is that what you're using) and would like to know just what the deal is here.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon I had white list these two http and https protocol and this  domain to 'http://maps.googleapis.com/*' so that the mobile device would allow me to use it

Comment: So it is working now? Your "kind of" made me think you were only partway there...